# Two scripts pulling data from an API work individually but not when on the same page

Tags: javascript, html-table

I've got a JS script that pulls data from an API and merges it all into a table, I need to do this twice for two different sets of data. Individually the scripts work as expected but when they're running on the same page only one of them displays any data.

I know the script tag isn't the best way to use JS but for my purpose everything needs to be contained in one block of html.

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  //Voting totals for current month

  var votingURLs = [
    'https://ark-servers.net/api/?object=servers&element=voters&limit=1000&key=7ImLVCEQFgOq9Ugz5G569nQJ5akmta8C2ty&month=current&format=json&rank=steamid',
    'https://ark-servers.net/api/?object=servers&element=voters&limit=1000&key=eJgmsMaw6Aor1bSD1r9wtyu1mBiLNjWSZW&month=current&format=json&rank=steamid',
    'https://ark-servers.net/api/?object=servers&element=voters&limit=1000&key=R72Uo7jcAXCVBjx1eGtDm8itWlrU59GHnuy&month=current&format=json&rank=steamid'
  ];

  var votingLists = [];
  var counter = 0;
  var finalList = [];
  var voters = [];
  var votesOfVoters = [];


  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.each(votingURLs, function(index, value) {
      var data;
      $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: value,
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
          votingLists[index] = data.voters;
          checkCompleteness();
        }
      });

    });
  });

  function checkCompleteness() {
    counter++;
    if (counter == (votingURLs.length)) {
      evalData();
    }
  }


  function evalData() {
    console.log("Start Evaluating");
    finalList = votingLists[0];

    $.each(votingLists, function(index, list) {
      if (index > 0) {
        $.each(list, function(index, value) {
          var steamid = value.steamid;
          var found = false;
          $.each(finalList, function(indexF, valueF) {
            if (steamid == valueF.steamid) {

              valueF.votes = parseInt(valueF.votes) + parseInt(value.votes);
              found = true;
              return false;

            }
          });
          if (!found) {
            finalList.push(value);
          }
        });


      }
    });

    displayingList(finalList);
  }



  function displayingList(list) {
    console.log("Start Displaying");

    list.sort(function(a, b) {
      return parseInt(b.votes, 10) - parseInt(a.votes, 10);

    });

    $.each(list, function(index, value) {

      var row = '<tr> <td>' + value.nickname + '</td> <td> ' + value.votes + '</td> </tr>';
      $('table[data="current_votes"] tbody').append(row);
    });
  }
</script>

<script>
  //Voting totals for previous month

  var votingURLs = [
    'https://ark-servers.net/api/?object=servers&element=voters&limit=1000&key=7ImLVCEQFgOq9Ugz5G569nQJ5akmta8C2ty&month=previous&format=json&rank=steamid',
    'https://ark-servers.net/api/?object=servers&element=voters&limit=1000&key=eJgmsMaw6Aor1bSD1r9wtyu1mBiLNjWSZW&month=previous&format=json&rank=steamid',
    'https://ark-servers.net/api/?object=servers&element=voters&limit=1000&key=R72Uo7jcAXCVBjx1eGtDm8itWlrU59GHnuy&month=previous&format=json&rank=steamid'
  ];

  var votingLists = [];
  var counter = 0;
  var finalList = [];
  var voters = [];
  var votesOfVoters = [];


  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.each(votingURLs, function(index, value) {
      var data;
      $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: value,
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
          votingLists[index] = data.voters;
          checkCompleteness();
        }
      });

    });
  });

  function checkCompleteness() {
    counter++;
    if (counter == (votingURLs.length)) {
      evalData();
    }
  }


  function evalData() {
    console.log("Start Evaluating");
    finalList = votingLists[0];

    $.each(votingLists, function(index, list) {
      if (index > 0) {
        $.each(list, function(index, value) {
          var steamid = value.steamid;
          var found = false;
          $.each(finalList, function(indexF, valueF) {
            if (steamid == valueF.steamid) {

              valueF.votes = parseInt(valueF.votes) + parseInt(value.votes);
              found = true;
              return false;

            }
          });
          if (!found) {
            finalList.push(value);
          }
        });


      }
    });

    displayingList(finalList);
  }



  function displayingList(list) {
    console.log("Start Displaying");

    list.sort(function(a, b) {
      return parseInt(b.votes, 10) - parseInt(a.votes, 10);

    });

    $.each(list, function(index, value) {

      var row = '<tr> <td>' + value.nickname + '</td> <td> ' + value.votes + '</td> </tr>';
      $('table[data="old_votes"] tbody').append(row);
    });
  }
</script>

<div>
  <table data="current_votes" id="current_totals">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Totals</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Votes</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div>
  <table data="old_votes" id="old_totals">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Totals</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Votes</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: you don't need code repeating in two script tags. you can just create the function with parameter and then pass different parameter for that function.(in your case parameter will be different url set).

Comment: I have no idea how to go about doing that

Comment: **You should refactor the code**, If you don't want to do that then please keep different variables for both script tag. This wills solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please take a look of below code. i added one extra parameter to distinguish current and old url and based on that in displayingList() we append data.

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  //Voting totals for current month

  var current_votingURLs = [
    'https://ark-servers.net/api/?object=servers&element=voters&limit=1000&key=7ImLVCEQFgOq9Ugz5G569nQJ5akmta8C2ty&month=current&format=json&rank=steamid',
    'https://ark-servers.net/api/?object=servers&element=voters&limit=1000&key=eJgmsMaw6Aor1bSD1r9wtyu1mBiLNjWSZW&month=current&format=json&rank=steamid',
    'https://ark-servers.net/api/?object=servers&element=voters&limit=1000&key=R72Uo7jcAXCVBjx1eGtDm8itWlrU59GHnuy&month=current&format=json&rank=steamid'
  ];

  var old_votingURLs = [
    'https://ark-servers.net/api/?object=servers&element=voters&limit=1000&key=7ImLVCEQFgOq9Ugz5G569nQJ5akmta8C2ty&month=previous&format=json&rank=steamid',
    'https://ark-servers.net/api/?object=servers&element=voters&limit=1000&key=eJgmsMaw6Aor1bSD1r9wtyu1mBiLNjWSZW&month=previous&format=json&rank=steamid',
    'https://ark-servers.net/api/?object=servers&element=voters&limit=1000&key=R72Uo7jcAXCVBjx1eGtDm8itWlrU59GHnuy&month=previous&format=json&rank=steamid'
  ];

  var votingLists = [];
  var counter = 0;
  var finalList = [];
  var voters = [];
  var votesOfVoters = [];
  var apiCounter = 0;

  $(document).ready(function() {
    function baseFunction(votingURLs, urlType){
        $.each(votingURLs, function(index, value) {
          var data;
          $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            url: value,
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {
              apiCounter++;
              console.log(data);
              votingLists[index] = data.voters;
              checkCompleteness(votingURLs, urlType);
            }
          });

        });
    }
    baseFunction(current_votingURLs,'current');
    baseFunction(old_votingURLs,'old');
  });

  function checkCompleteness(votingURLs, urlType) {
    counter++;
    console.log('In checkCompleteness');
    //if (counter == (votingURLs.length)) {
      evalData(urlType);
    //}
  }


  function evalData(urlType) {
    console.log("Start Evaluating");
    console.log("Start Evaluating", urlType);
    finalList = votingLists[0];

    $.each(votingLists, function(index, list) {
      if (index > 0) {
        $.each(list, function(index, value) {
          var steamid = value.steamid;
          var found = false;
          $.each(finalList, function(indexF, valueF) {
            if (steamid == valueF.steamid) {

              valueF.votes = parseInt(valueF.votes) + parseInt(value.votes);
              found = true;
              return false;

            }
          });
          if (!found) {
            finalList.push(value);
          }
        });


      }
    });

    displayingList(finalList, urlType);
  }



  function displayingList(list, urlType) {
    console.log("Start Displaying");
    console.log("urlType", urlType);
    list.sort(function(a, b) {
      return parseInt(b.votes, 10) - parseInt(a.votes, 10);

    });
    if(urlType == 'current') {
        $.each(list, function(index, value) {

          var row = '<tr> <td>' + value.nickname + '</td> <td> ' + value.votes + '</td> </tr>';
          $('table[data="current_votes"] tbody').append(row);
        });
    }else {
        $.each(list, function(index, value) {

          var row = '<tr> <td>' + value.nickname + '</td> <td> ' + value.votes + '</td> </tr>';
          $('table[data="old_votes"] tbody').append(row);
        });
    }
    console.log(apiCounter);
  }
</script>

<div>
  <table data="current_votes" id="current_totals">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Totals</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Username new</th>
      <th>Votes</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div>
  <table data="old_votes" id="old_totals">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Totals</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Votes</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, still only one table displaying and that one table seems to only be pulling data from 2 of the url's

Comment: Ok... every time I refresh the page it loads different portions of the data but never all of it. Now I'm confused.

Comment: The first table seems to be reliably showing all the data now, however the second table is now showing nothing.

Comment: Nope, still only one table

Comment: Nope, without that function it just pulls one url of data and skips everything else completely. Shall we move this to a chat? It won't let me do the auto thing because I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: can you create plunker of your working code https://plnkr.co/ ? chat needs 20 reputation points.

Comment: I'm still only getting data in one table on that one... Just tried in chrome and edge so it's not my browser.

Comment: check this now https://plnkr.co/edit/qcZc85BofU3sRTv1IG3T?p=preview. I forgot to save the last one. sorry.

Comment: There is data in both tables, but it looks like it's doubled up the same data in both now

Comment: data is different,if you compare.

Comment: It's different, but it's not the right data, the highest in the first table should be 93 and the highest in the second table should be 84. There's some values in both tables upwards of 140

Comment: check the urs you are using to get ajax response from. is your first  question resolved?

Comment: Kind of, now I need to work out why it's pulling the wrong data